# Is there a way to debug a release version when loading dlls?

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, dll, startup

I am developing a 64 bit C++ application using Visual Studio 2015, Qt 5.5 and OpenCV3.0. The application runs well on the pc I use for developing in Release and Debug version. But the same application runs only in Debug on other PCs, and in release version I get this Error Message:

```
 The application was unable to start correctly 0xc0000005, Click Ok toclose the application:
```

[image]

I created a dump file to open it using visual studio debugger, it shows that the application stops when loading the dll before loading opencv_imgproc300.dll.

I tried to review the event viewer but I did not find this error there.

Is there a method to debug a release version in startup when loading the dlls to know which the cause of the problem?

Comment: easiest first step would be to run dependency walker on the target pc and open your exe in it http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: You might try using ProcessMonitor from the sysinternals-suite. There is no guarantee, but it might show something helpful (it certainly shows a lot).

Comment: I tried this from sysinternals: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx . but it doesn,t show the missing or corrupted dlls. For dependencywalker, I use better the Module window in Visual Studio Debugger, It shows all the loaded dlls and the order of loading, I find it more helpful.

Comment: I would try compiling the release version without optimization and debug information (pdb). This can give you a hint on the client's computer where is the crash...

Comment: *I use better the Module window* are you sure? Dependency walker effectively shows dlls which should be loaded and marks them when they cannot be found, whereas the module window only shows already loaded dll (afaik) - moreover dependency walker is standalone so you can use it on any pc without installtion, you can't do that with the debugger (either you need to install VS or else remote debugging tools)

Comment: I will try the release with debug information. but does it links correctly with the release dll?

Comment: @stijn Yes.For debugging purpose, I was obliged to install visual studio on the client PC to know the order of the loaded DLLs. But dependencywalker is a very good solution where you cannot use visual studio as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great effort, I solved the issue, It was because the opencv_imgproc300.dll was corrupted, It has the true size but inside is corrupted, I checked with dependency walker and found that there is great difference between the linked DLL in the Application folder and  the original dll file.
As a summary, If you want to debug a release version when starting up, you have many methods. We will describe two of them:

1. Compiling your Release version with Debug Info, and run your application like if it was in Debug version. If the application stops before loading a DLL. This DLL is probably corrupted or missing. This link show how to compile your Release version with Debug informations: [How to: Debug a Release Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx).
2. Using [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), You open your release version application with this tool and you will find if there is any corrupted or missing dll  that it needs when starting up (It is marked with red color in dependency walker). If you application is built in 64 bit, your should use the x64 version of dependency walker. If it is x86, you should use the x86 version of dependency walker. If you use the x86 version to open the x64 version of your application,  you can see some false error related to linking with system DLL in their x86 version, but don't care about it, it is a bug in Dependency Walker itself.

Comment: re 2: for x64 applications use the x64 version of dependency walker, for x86 the x86 version